# Could any one help me to make my query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could any one help me to make my query more efficient?
I'm a beginner of SQL,
as I know for efficient is to use index or primary key to let the B-tree search faster,therefore,I've already set the primary key for `rid` and index for `(Date, Time)`
However, my query is still too inefficient to output the result.

I'm trying to find the sensor(sid) which has the largest interval on '2017-03-04'.
Here is my code:

```
select tmp4.sid as largest_ivl_sensor
from
(
    select tmp3.sid, MAX(tmp3.Dif) as max_for_each
    from
    (
        select tmp1.sid, MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(tmp2.Time, INTERVAL tmp1.Time HOUR_SECOND))) as Dif
        from
            (
            select se.sid, r.rid, r.Time
            from (select rr.rid, rr.Time from records rr where rr.Date = '2017-03-04') as r, send se
            where se.rid = r.rid
            order by se.sid
            ) as tmp1
            INNER JOIN
            (
            select se2.sid, r2.rid, r2.Time
            from (select rr2.rid, rr2.Time from records rr2 where rr2.Date = '2017-03-04') as r2, send se2
            where se2.rid = r2.rid
            order by se2.sid
            ) as tmp2 ON tmp1.sid = tmp2.sid and TIME_TO_SEC(tmp1.Time) <= TIME_TO_SEC(tmp2.Time) and tmp1.rid <> tmp2.rid
        GROUP BY tmp1.sid, tmp1.Time
    ) as tmp3
    GROUP BY tmp3.sid
) as tmp4
group by tmp4.max_for_each
having tmp4.max_for_each = MAX(tmp4.max_for_each);
```

And here is the schema:
records

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rid         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Date        | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Time        | time        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Humidity    | double(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Temperature | double(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PM1         | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PM10        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PM25        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

send

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rid   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here is a example:

```
| rid |sid |   Time   |
|   1 |  a | 00:00:00 |
|   2 |  a | 00:01:00 |
|   3 |  b | 00:05:00 |
|   4 |  b | 00:07:00 |
|   5 |  b | 00:11:00 |
|   6 |  c | 00:00:00 |
|   7 |  c | 00:03:00 |
|   8 |  c | 00:04:00 |
```

desired result:

```
| sid|
|   b|
```

Since it has largest interval 4 minutes

Another example:

```
| rid |sid |   Time   |
|   1 |  a | 00:00:00 |
|   2 |  b | 00:11:00 |
|   3 |  c | 00:04:00 |
|   4 |  b | 00:07:00 |
|   5 |  a | 00:01:00 |
|   6 |  c | 00:00:00 |
|   7 |  c | 00:03:00 |
|   8 |  b | 00:05:00 |
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an explanation of what it is doing.  The place to start with performance is understanding what needs to be done.

Comment: I`m guessing that the largest interval means some sort of contiguous interval per that day.In that case look into rownumber per group in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of variables in your SQL to keep track of the differences on-the-fly. Also, `order by` in combination with `limit 1` is handy for getting the record with the highest value:

```
select     sid,
           max(diff) as max_diff
from       (
                select     if(sid = @s, secs - @t, null) as diff,
                           @t := secs as secs,
                           @s := sid as sid
                from       (select     sid, 
                                       time_to_sec(time) as secs
                            from       records
                            inner join send on send.rid = records.rid
                            where      date = '2017-03-04'
                            order by   sid, time
                           ) ordered
                cross join (select @s := null, @t := null) init
           ) data
group by   sid
order by   max_diff desc
limit 1;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/FBEE59525).

Comment: sorry, perhaps I'm not explain well on my example.
`rid` is id of each record(row) and it is set to be auto_increment when the table `records` created.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the example is like

    | rid |sid |    Time    |
    |   1 |  a | 00:00:00 |
    |   2 |  a | 00:01:00 |
    |   3 |  b | 00:05:00 |
    |   4 |  b | 00:07:00 |
    |   5 |  b | 00:11:00 |
    |   6 |  c | 00:00:00 |
    |   7 |  c | 00:03:00 |
    |   8 |  c | 00:04:00 |

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot read that. Could you please edit your question?

Comment: What if the record is like the 'another example' which I've just edit.
Could this variable method still work for it?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I've learned a lot from this.